# Вызвать нестатичный метод из другого класса не создавая экземпляра

Tags: android, java

Есть активити, в которой есть метод, который обновляет данные в `ListView`.

В этом методе еще много методов, эти методы тоже содержат некоторые методы и переменные. Этот метод нное количество раз вызывается в этом активити. Но мне понадобилось один раз вызывать его из другого класса. Можно конечно сделать все методы и переменные `public static` (что и было сделано) и спокойно вызывать метод из другого класса, не создавая экземпляра, но это не есть правильно.

---

Так вот, вопрос: каким образом можно вызывать метод из другого класса?

Comment: вы бы лучше дали больше контекста, а то однозначно пытаетесь какой-то костыль сделать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никак. `non-static` метод на то и `non-static`, что требует наличия экземпляра класса, его содержащего.

А вообще, какая-то странная проблема у вас. Практически уверен, что то, что вы хотите сделать, отлично решается при помощи `Intent` и `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Есть класс, который наследуется от ListView. В нем я отлавливаю касания пользователя. MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP и т д. Если условие прошло успешно - надо обновить список методом Reload. А он находится в другом классе.

Comment: Почему бы просто не вызывать `notifyDataSetChanged()` у адаптера `ListView`?

Comment: для обновления - я очищаю список, затем отправляю запрос на сервер, сервер возвращает ответ в формате json, я парсю и вбиваю заного данные.

Comment: Ну так делайте `sendBroadcast()`, когда нужно обновить список, а `Activity` пускай в `BroadcastReceiver` ждёт этого `Intent`'а, а по его получении, соответственно, осуществляет обновление.

Comment: Усложняете. @dexter, по моему это идеальный вариант для использования паттерна "Слушатель"

Comment: falstaf, шикарная вещь. спасибо. разобрался.